# How to create Firebase security rule that allows members of a doc to write that doc

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

My firebase database contains families.  These families have `parents` and other attributes like address, etc..  I'd like to allow either parent write access to their family document and have read-only access to other families.  How do I express this with the security rules syntax?

Say the data looks like this:

```
families (collection)
    "TheSmiths" (doc) {
        parents: [{ firstname: "John", role:"dad", userId:"xxxx" },
                  { firstname: "Joan", role:"mom", userId:"yyyy" } ],
        address: "123 Oak Lane"
    }
    "TheJoneses" (doc) etc.
```

My best shot at rules so far looks like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // any user can read the families
    match /families/{anyDocument} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    // here's my problem
    match /families/{anyDocument} {
      allow read, write: if resource.data.parents.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

The second rule is trying to say, "allow read and write of a family doc if the user's id is stored in one of the parents.  The problem I'm having is syntax for "one of the" parents.  Maybe I could say:

```
if ((resource.data.parents[0].userId == request.auth.uid) ||
    (resource.data.parents[1].userId == request.auth.uid))
```

Can I?  Even if I can, the data might contain more or less than two adults who can be considered parents for the purpose of editing.  Am I even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As looking into Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#the_resource_variable)

you can try something like this

```
match /families/{anyDocument} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow write: if resource.data.parents.userId in [(request.auth.uid)];
}
```

which says allow read if your authenticated and write if you are listed in `parents/userId` map path.

i didn't checked myself, hope this will help.

Comment: I missed the more complex expressions in the doc.  Thanks.  The way I will use your suggesting is to keep an array of owning userIDs, then ask if the request.auth.uid is `in` resource.data.owningUserIds.